# I cant find file explorer on Spyder

Tags: python, spyder

I can't seem to find file explorer on python to make a file my directory only variable explorer

[image]

Comment: go to `view` -> `panes` and select `Files` or press `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`X`

Answer (score 5):

One way to open the file explorer is to use the key combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>.